# What does "it's alive" mean in this conversation?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, water-for-elephants

In **Water For Elephants**, Old Jacob and Charlie with rings argue in the rain outside the circus:

> Old Jacob: I'm telling you, I didn't come with the home! Why don't you
>   take those rings out of your head, and maybe you won't be deaf and
>   dumb!
>
> Charlie: Well, **it's alive.** (Saying this words to his friend who is
>   standing beside him)
>
> Old Jacob: I'm sorry, kid. I didn't mean that. Your rings look very
>   pretty.

What does "it's alive" mean in this conversation?

Comment: Why creating that many accounts?

Comment: @AJ Probably to avoid the rate limiting that gets imposed when asking a lot of poorly received questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume with the context that Old Jacob is outside a retirement home, has probably been sitting still and quiet till his outburst here?

If Old Jacob looked asleep or even dead at the time then the "It's alive" seems an allusion to Dr Frankenstein exclaiming "It's ALIVE!" when his monster first moves.

Parents also often do this when their teenage children wake up sometime after midday.

Comment: @Chenmunka sorry about that don't know how that slipped in. Perils of multitasking